# Azure Devops test Suites add time evaluation

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, test-suite, azure-boards

we added a new mandatory field "time evaluation" for every test case, this represent how many hours should this test case take, and it is showing under cases table.

[image]
Is there a way to do the same for the test Suites (left side menu)?

We will like to know (and have it on display) how much will the test suites take in total..

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

As of this time, however, it is not supported to add a custom field in test suites that can automatically sum time. But you can use chart as workaround.

---

**Prerequisite:** Your time evaluation field should be Integer or Decimal type. Otherwise, you cannot sum it.

**Detailed steps:**

1. Select "Chart" tab. Click "New" and select "new test case chart".

   [image]
2. Select "Stacked bar". In Aggregation part, select **Sum** of **Time Evaluation**. Then set "Y-axis" and "Group by" parts based on your personal habits. In the below example, I am using "State" in "Group by" and "Assign to" in "Y-axis".

   [image]

   After that, you will see time evaluation sum in "Total".

Comment: This will give a static amount for the test suite, right? What about a chart/plot showing how many hours have been completed how many are still required? Is this possible?